Finding average tries to get a positive result while knowing probability of getting a positive result in n tries
so if I have a test that returs either a positive or a negative result but the result depends on the number of tries, is there a way to know how many tries on avarage would it take to get a positive result?
Say, if n is the number of tries and p is probability of getting a positive result in n tries, then with n=1 p=0, n=2 p=0, ... n=9 p≈0.0009, n=10 p≈0.005, n=11 p≈0.01, ... n=25 p≈0.59, n=26 p≈0.63, and so on.. (So you cant get positive result if you do less then 9 tries, if you do 9 tries then there's a 0.09% chance of you getting a positive result, with 10 tries it becomes 0.5% etc.)
In my case p = f(n) looks like this:
$$
\left( 1 - \frac{9×8^n-36×7^n+84×6^n-126×5^n+126×4^n-84×3^n+36×2^n-9×1^n}{9^n} \right)
$$
Ideally I would like to know avarage tries it takes to get a positive result based only on this formula, but here's some more background to my question..
Basically I want to find a way to mathematically calculate ammount of tries it takes to get all items out of a lootbox at least once, where items can repeat and all drop rates are equal, the formula I attached above shows probability of getting all 9 items if 1 lootbox drops 1 out of 9 possibile items but items can repeat.
Simulating it I get an avarage of 25-26 tries to get a positive result but I cant really figure out a way of how to get there without brute forcing it.

Are you saying that you have  a sequence of probabilities ${p_n}$ where $p_n$ denotes the probability of success on trial $#n$?   If so, the probability that the first success occurs on trial $n$ is $\psi_n=p_n\times \prod_{k=1}^{n-1}(1-p_k)$ and you can use that to compute the expected first success, $\sum n\psi_n$.

I am, of course, assuming that each trial is independent, though you did not say that.

@lulu If I dont misunderstand you, then no. In my case p is probability of success in general with n trials. Tho it is guaranteed that p(n+1) >= p(n) but p denotes probability of success on one of the trials if you do n trials.

Ok, so then the probability of getting a success on the $n^{th}$ trial is $\phi_n=p_n-p_{n-1}$  Use that in place of $p_n$ in my first comment.

I just tried writing a python code for that but got 14.6 as an output which is considerably  lower then expected

Huh, it also seems to really depend on wether or not f(0) is 1.. With default formula f(0) is 1 and it outputs  29 as avarage tries, but if I change it  so that f(0) is 0 (which is logical because you cant get a positive result in 0 tries) then it returns 14.6 as mentioned above

Yes, what i wrote is wrong but I'm not sure why.  It is giving me inconsistent results.  I will post a corrected version once I have it.

Silly mistake, the probability that the first success occurs on trial $n$ is $p_n-p_{n-1}$.

To correct an error in the comments:
Here, $p_n$ denotes the probability that you have observed at least $1$ success in the first $n$ trials.  Thus, $1-p_n$ is the probability that you have observed $n$ fails in the first $n$ trials.
Let $\psi_n$ denote the probability that the first success occurs on trial $n$.  Then, of course, $$\psi_n=p_n-p_{n-1}$$.
The expected value in question can now be computed as $$E=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n\psi_n$$
and truncating at $100$ terms gives the approximation $$25.45319$$ which is in line with the simulated results.

That, turned out to be easier then expected.. ha ha. Thanks!

Yeah, sorry about the confusion.
